# Linear programming and event occurrence

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Suppose we have N (in this example N = 3) events that can happen depending on some variables. Each of them can generate certain profit or loses (event1 = 300, event2 = -100, event3 = 200), they are constrained by rules when they happen.

event 1 happens only when x > 5,

event 2 happens only when x = 2 and y = 3

event 3 happens only when x is odd.

The problem is to know the maximum profit.

Assume x, y are integer numbers >= 0

In the real problem there are many events and many dimensions. 
(the solution should not be specific)

My question is:

Is this linear programming problem? If yes please provide solution to the example problem using this approach. If no please suggest some algorithms to optimize such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be formulated as a [mixed integer linear program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming#Variants). This is a linear program where some of the variables are constrained to be integer. Contrary to linear programs, solving the general integer program is NP-hard. However, there are many commercial or [open source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502102/best-open-source-mixed-integer-optimization-solver) solvers that can solve efficiently large-scale problems. For up to 300 variables and constraints, you can use excel's solver.

Here is a way to formulate the above constraints:

[image]

If you go down this route, you might find [this document](http://www.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/aimms3om_integerprogrammingtricks.pdf) useful.

the last constraint in an interesting one. I am assuming that `x` has to be integer, but if `x` can be either integer or continuous I will edit the answer accordingly.

I hope this helps!

**Edit**: `L` and `U` above should be interpreted as `L1` and `U1`.

**Edit 2**: z2 needs to changed to (1-z2) on the 3rd and 4th constraint.

Comment: Seems like correct direction, but I need some time to soak it in :)

Comment: Cool :) If you would like me to elaborate on how the constraints model the events let me know. In a nutshell, starting from each event on the `x` or `y`, the constraints should lead to unique values of `zi`. Also, the "not occurrence" of events should lead to the `z`s being zero.

Comment: I don't understand the 3rd and 4th constraints, when z2 = 0, it should be 0 <= x - 2 <= 0, but there will be -e <= x - 2 <= e, and similar for second one, why do we need this number 'e' here?

Comment: I edited it (in `edit 2`) so that it works correctly: `z2 == 1 => x - 2 == 0`. The `epsilon` quantity is added for numerical accuracy: the solution of a linear program uses floating point arithmetic, which means that constraints are correct within a certain tolerance threshold. I would select `epsilon = 10e-8`. Removing the `epsilon` from the formulation [can lead to infeasibilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001462/solving-an-integer-linear-program-why-are-solvers-claiming-a-solvable-instance). So although conceptually is not needed, it helps in practice.

Answer (score 0):

A specific answer:

seems more like a mathematical calculation than a programming problem, can't you just run a loop for x= 1->1000 to see what results occur?

for the example:

as x = 2 or 3 = -200 then x > 2 or 3, and if x < 5 doesn't get the 300, so all that is really happening is x > 5 and x = odd = maximum results.

x = 7 = 300 + 200 . = maximum profit for x

A general answer:

I don't see how to answer the question without seeing what the events are and how the events effect X ? Weather it's a linear or functional (mathematical) answer seems rather beside the point of finding the desired solution.

Comment: You don't need to know what the events are you just need to know when they occur (e.g. x > 5 and y <= 2) and how much profit or loss you get from it. Also the brute-force solution is not ok here (because of many dimensions in real problem and a lot of events) that's why I started to work towards linear-programming (or maybe non-linear) optimization.